# Simple $\mathfrak{g}$-modules are cyclic.

Tags: vector-spaces, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Could someone tell me if my proof is correct?

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra over a field of charateristic $0$.$ \ \ $If $ \ V \ $ is a simple $\mathfrak{g}$-module, then for $ \ v \in V \setminus \{0\}:$ $$  \mathfrak{g} \cdot \langle v  \rangle \neq {0} \text{ or } \langle v  \rangle \ \text{ would be a subrepresentation of } \ V, \text{ thus } \ \mathfrak{g} \cdot \langle v  \rangle = V.$$

Hence $V$ is a cyclic $\mathfrak{g}$-module.

Comment: Well, you want $U(\mathfrak{g})\cdot v$ instead of $\mathfrak{g}\cdot\langle v\rangle$, but otherwise the reasoning is correct.

Comment: @DavidHill doesn't $ \ \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})\cdot v$ cyclic  $ \ \Rightarrow \ \mathfrak{g} \cdot v$ cyclic?

Comment: The problem is the notation $\mathfrak{g}\cdot v=\{ x.v\mid x\in\mathfrak{g}\}$. Elements of the module generated by $v$ have the form $\sum_{x_1,\ldots,x_k\in\mathfrak{g}}a(x_1,\ldots,x_k)x_1x_2\cdots x_k\cdot v$.

Comment: The way to formally make sense of "the submodule generated by $v$" is the intersection of all $\mathfrak{g}$-submodules of $V$ containing $v$. Informally, this means the linear span of what you get by applying $\mathfrak{g}$ to $v$ over and over again. A formal way of making sense of it again is $U(\mathfrak{g}) v$.